# SQL : create column that count occurences of an other column values

Tags: sql

I have a table with :

```
ID | name
 1 | aaa
 2 | aaa
 3 | bbb
 4 | aaa
```

And I would like to get the count of the column "name" in an other column :

```
ID | name | name_count
 1 | aaa  | 3
 2 | aaa  | 3   
 3 | bbb  | 1
 4 | aaa  | 3
```

I can't manage to make a good query to do such a thing. Any idea ?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as name_count
from t;
```

Comment: How do I change this to an UPDATE query to fill a existing column? This does not work : `UPDATE t SET name_count= count(ID) over(partition by name)`

Comment: Managed to do it : `UPDATE t SET name_count = (SELECT count(ID) over(partition by name) FROM t)`

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution that works without window functions (i.e. you still use MySQL 5.x):

```
select t.id, t.name, c.name_count
from t
join (
  select name, count(*) as name_count
  from t
  group by name 
) as c using (name);
```